# Question about saves from WoL carrying over to HoTS

Tags: starcraft-2

In terms of story-line, are there significant changes to the "Heart of the Swarm" campaign due to the choices made from "Wings of Liberty?" If so, what saves are the choices taken from, the most recent WoL play through, or the first time you played it?

I'm very curious to know.